How can the stress-energy tensor $T^{μν}$ be unique when the Lagrangian $L$ is not?
A relation (or definition) between the stress-energy tensor and the Lagrangian in GR is routinely seen:
$$T^{μν} = -2 \frac{∂L}{∂g_{μν}} - g^{μν} L \quad\quad(*)$$
(or some variation of this, depending upon sign conventions).
I have a simple question. A Lagrangian is not unique (in terms of generating the equations of motion): it can be multiplied by a constant, for example, or a constant can be added. Yet in $(*)$ we see both $L$ and $∂L/∂g_{μν}$. It seems as though such changes to $L$ would change $T^{μν}$. How can $T^{μν}$ be unique when $L$ is not?

The magnitude of T is only useful when comparing to another quantity, like the Einstein tensor in Einstein's equations. If the full Lagrangian is scaled, it doesn't change Einstein's equation since the scalar curvature term is scaled as well. If every term except the curvature term is scaled, then it means that matter affects gravity more, and is a change in the theory. If a constant is added, Einstein's equations get changed by the cosmological constant (in fact, since we can measure the latter, we know the vacuum energy density of the true Lagrangian).

This is a very interesting question. In addition to your examples, I should mention that there are examples of very different Lagrangians giving the same result on-shell. Lemos's book on Analytical Mechanics has an example with the harmonic oscillator somewhere, and the Nambu-Goto and Polyakov actions for string theory are another example.

Adding a constant to the Lagrangian actually does affect the physics when gravity is involved. This constant term has an interpretation as the energy of the vacuum, or the cosmological constant. For example , let's say you shift the Lagrangian $L$ by a constant $-2\Lambda$. The reason it affects the physics is because $$S = \int d^4x \mathbf{\sqrt{-g}} \left(L - 2 \Lambda\right)$$ and you can see that the metric determinant couples to this constant. If you compute the stress energy tensor, $\Lambda$ is the cosmological constant.
If you wanted to interpret the $\sqrt{-g}$ as being part of the Lagrangian and add a constant $C$ outside of the parentheses, like $$S = \int d^4x \left(C +\sqrt{-g} L \right)\,, $$ then $C$ would not affect the equations of motion at all, like you said. But this Lagrangian is not diffeomorphism invariant unless $C=0$, because there's nothing to cancel the coordinate change of the measure. Now, you could always just demand that $C$ transforms under diffeomorphisms in the right way to restore the symmetry. But then, you will find that it is proportional to $\sqrt{-g}$, and you're right back where you started.
As for rescaling the Lagrangian by a constant, that would also rescale the Einstein tensor by the same constant so the equations of motion would be identical. Nothing has really changed here. In the quantum theory, that's the same as just changing your units for $\hbar$.
Finally, adding a total derivative to the Lagrangian does not affect the equations of motion, but can affect what boundary conditions are allowed for your fields, so it will change what field configurations are physical. In that sense, it can indirectly affect the possible values of the stress energy tensor, but not its functional form.

In principle, for standard local Lagrangians of field theory, the ambiguity of the Lagrangian density of the matter field $\phi$ amounts to  a total derivative (just beacuse it should not change the equation of motion) so that it does not affect the action $S[g,\phi]$.  The stress energy tensor can be obtained out of the action directly
$$T_{\mu\nu}(x) = \frac{-2}{\sqrt{-g}}\frac{S[g,\phi]}{\delta g^{\mu\nu}(x)}\:.$$
Hence it is invariant under changes of the Lagrangian due to added total derivatives.
You cannot multiply the lagrangian with a constant without multiplying all the other lagrangians of all systems with the same constant, as the total Lagrangian matters, not separately each Lagrangians.
This total lagrangian is the sum of all Lagrangians and interaction lagrangians of each pair.
So, yes there is also this ambiguity, but in practice  it is equivalent to change the action unit.

If you get $T$ that way from the Lagrangian, it need not be unique. This is just like with Hamiltonian derived from a Lagrangian in  ordinary mechanics; it is not unique, because different $L$ (e.g. different by a total time derivative of a function of coordinates and time) will give you different $H$.
$T$ being unique is an idea that stems from Einstein's equations; these equate $T$ with a certain quantity computed from geometry of spacetime (e.g. from the metric tensor). Thus if geometry(metric tensor) is fixed, there can be only one $T$ that, in Einstein's theory, is consistent with it.
